# Understanding priority_queue by problem : Find K Closest Elements Solution

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, priority-queue

I was solving one problem on leetcode [problem](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/binary-search/135/template-iii/945/) - **Find K Closest Elements**.

Here is my IDE code : [ide.geeksforgeeks](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/2sqTJRu1ap)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>

std::vector<int> findClosestElements(std::vector<int>& arr, int k, int x) 
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    // min heap
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>,
    std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>> pq;
    
    std::cout << "Debug queue : \n";
    for (auto it : arr)
    {
        int closest = abs(it - x);
        pq.push(std::make_pair(closest, it));        
        //std::cout << closest << " : " << it << "\n";
        
        if (pq.size() > k)
        {
            pq.pop();     
        }
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nIterating queue : \n";
    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        res.push_back(pq.top().second);
        std::cout << pq.top().first << " : " << pq.top().second << "\n";
        pq.pop();
    }
    
    std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
    return res;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    auto res = findClosestElements(arr, 4, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

While I was iterating the queue, I can not see the minimum number : `0 : 3` which should be the top element of priority_queue. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Could you brief more what you are suggesting?

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that you use the third (optional) template argument to reverse ordering. Then you need to specify the second as well.

Comment: If you put back the output in the insertion loop, what is the output your program shows? Does it output what you expect it to output? What about if you print the element you pop when `pq.size() > k`? Does it pop what you expect?

Comment: P.S. All questions referencing Leetcode are off-topic for Stackoverflow, because their site appears to require a login. It's not just all questions on Stackoverflow require all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text*** and links to external web sites are off-topic, but here you can't even see Leetcode's latest nonsense and what they're babbling about, without a login to their site.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Thanks! it helps, I was not getting expected output on pq.pop().  Max heaps solves the problem.

Comment: OT:  `it` is confusing naming in a range based for loop, because it is typically used for iterators, but your `it` is not an iterator

Answer (score -1):

Max heaps solves the problem.

```
vector<int> findClosestElements(vector<int>& arr, int k, int x) 
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<int, int>> pq;

    for (auto it : arr)
    {
        int closest = abs(it - x);
        //std::cout << closest << " : " << it << "\n";
        pq.push(std::make_pair(closest, it));

        if (pq.size() > k)
        {
            pq.pop();     
        }
    }

    //std::cout << "\nDebug queue : \n";
    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        res.push_back(pq.top().second);
        //std::cout << pq.top().first << " : " << pq.top().second << "\n";
        pq.pop();
    }

    std::sort(res.begin(), res.end());
    return res;
}
```